# How to make the code in my function return editted dataframes

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am attempting to use ifelse statements in R to add a specific prefix to my dataframes.

I have two issues with my code at the moment.

1) When I try to wrap this in a function it does not return the edited dataframes.

2) the no = parameter of the ifelse statement I have put in repeats itself, how do I make this only repeat once?

Would appreciate any help.

note. I am using some made up data in this example, due to professional reasons.

---

dput(head(Player1)):

```
structure(list(Class = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("fighter", 
"paladin", "rouge", "sorceror", "wizard"), class = "factor"), 
Race = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("elf", 
"gnome", "human", "orc"), class = "factor"), alignment = structure(c(4L, 
2L, 1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("CE", "CG", "LG", "NE", "NN"), class = "factor"), 
Level = c(6, 7, 1, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

dput(head(Player2)):

```
structure(list(Class = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("fighter", 
"paladin", "rouge", "sorceror", "wizard"), class = "factor"), 
Race = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("elf", 
"gnome", "human", "orc"), class = "factor"), alignment = structure(c(4L, 
2L, 1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("CE", "CG", "LG", "NE", "NN"), class = "factor"), 
Level = c(6, 7, 1, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

Let's say we have two players John (player1) and Lucy (player2) and we want to add a prefix's on their colnames. I have achieved this by using the code below.

```
ifelse(test = grepl('Johns', names(Player1)) == F, 
         yes = colnames(Player1) <- paste('Johns', colnames(Player1), sep = '_'),
         no = print('Player info is fine'))
```

The output here works and all columns get 'Johns_' as a prefix
However, when I attempt to wrap this into a function for both players the data frames there is no change.

Function:

```
Addnames <- function(Player1, Player2){
  ifelse(test = grepl('Johns', names(Player1)) == F, 
         yes = colnames(Player1) <- paste('Johns', colnames(Player1), sep = '_'),
         no = print('Player info is fine'))
  ifelse(test = grepl('Lucys', names(Player2)) == F, 
         yes = colnames(Player2) <- paste('Lucys', colnames(Player2), sep = '_'),
         no = print('Player info is fine'))
return(Player1)
return(Player2)
}

Addnames(Player1, Player2)
```

This does not edit the colnames of the data frames.

---

My ideal output is to have 'Johns_' and 'Lucys_' as a prefix on each column name for Player1 and Player2 data frames, respectively.

I would to do this in a function.

Another issue I have is inside the ifelse statement if no = 'Player info is fine' repeats itself for each column name. How do I get this to only repeat itself once.

Again any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your first issue is that a function cannot modify objects in the global environment (outside the function) if you do not either specifically tell it to do so or assign the output of the function to a variable in the global environment. Your second issue is that the first `return()` call exits the function so you cannot have two separate `return()` calls in the function.

Comment: I am not sure but do you want to change column names for both dataframes ? Do you need `names(Player1) <- paste0("Johns_", names(Player1));
names(Player2) <- paste0("Lucys_", names(Player2))` ?

Comment: Hmmm...your exact reproducible post *does* show columns of first data frame is modified. See demo: https://rextester.com/DYV6690. Simply adjust the return for both data frames: `return(list(Player1, Player2)`.

Comment: @Parfait but not that this will return a single list with two elements, one for Player1 and one for Player2. You can't directly assign that result into the two dataframes. (I'm sure you know that, just wanted to alert the OP).

Comment: @iod ... OP should be working with lists of data frames especially if they are similarly structured! Avoid flooding global environment with separate like-objects.

Comment: No argument there (though I seriously hate working with lists)

Comment: @RonakShah Yes that was my intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have more than just two players, you'll probably want a re-usable function. Similar to the above solution by fmarm but recycling more of your original code:

```
Addnames <- function(player, namestring){
  ifelse(test = grepl(namestring, names(player)) == F, 
         yes = colnames(player) <- paste(namestring, colnames(player), sep = '_'),
         no = print('Player info is fine'))
  return(player)
}


Player1 <- Addnames(player=Player1, namestring="Johns")
Player2 <- Addnames(player=Player2, namestring="Lucys")
```

Edit: further assuming that "Lucys" is actually called "Lucy", the addition of the "s" can of course also be done within the function:

```
Addnames <- function(player, namestring){
  ifelse(test = grepl(namestring, names(player)) == F, 
         yes = colnames(player) <- paste(namestring, "s", colnames(player), sep = '_'),
         no = print('Player info is fine'))
  return(player)
}


Player1 <- Addnames(player=Player1, namestring="John")
Player2 <- Addnames(player=Player2, namestring="Lucy")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it in an function, I would rather create a function that takes two arguments : the name of the dataframe and the name of the player, so there is only one thing to return : the dataframe with correct column names

```
Addnames <- function(player_df,player_name){
   column_names_to_change <- which(!grepl('Johns', names(player_df)))
   colnames(player_df)[column_names_to_change]  <- paste(player_name,colnames(player_df)[column_names_to_change],sep="_")
   return(player_df)
}
```

To change the dataframe after the function, you need to reassign the result back to Player1

```
Player1 <- Addnames(Player1,"Johns")
Player2 <- Addnames(Player2,"Lucys")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use lists and run `Map` to iterate element-wise between players and correspondong data frames without any `ifelse` conditional logic. Even use `setNames` for right-hand side function return.

```
player_list <- c("John", "Lucy")    

df_list <- list(Player1, Player2)

# RENAME COLUMNS ELEMENTWISE
new_df_list <- Map(function(nm, df) setNames(df, paste0(nm, "_", colnames(df))),
                   player_list, df_list)

# OUTPUT DF ELEMENTS
new_df_list$John
#   John_Class John_Race John_alignment John_Level
# 1    paladin     human             NE          6
# 2    fighter       elf             CG          7
# 3     wizard       orc             CE          1
# 4   sorceror     human             NN          2
# 5      rouge     gnome             LG          4

new_df_list$Lucy
#   Lucy_Class Lucy_Race Lucy_alignment Lucy_Level
# 1    paladin     human             NE          6
# 2    fighter       elf             CG          7
# 3     wizard       orc             CE          1
# 4   sorceror     human             NN          2
# 5      rouge     gnome             LG          4
```